# Why jouranlctl uses --utc by default when running without root privigies?

Tags: systemd-journald, timezone, journalctl

On a host running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I notice that, by default, `journalctl` (without root privileges) is the same as `journalctl --utc`, but with root privileges `journalctl` honors the time zone (as shown with `timedatectl`).

```
$ journalctl | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 1-3
Sep 11 16:38:00

$ sudo journalctl | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 1-3
Sep 11 13:38:13

$ timedatectl | grep "Time zone" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 5-6
(-03, -0300)
```

- I suspect [Homebrew/linuxbrew](https://brew.sh/) is the culprit, even `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/etc/systemd/journald.conf` has all its line commented out, but:

  ```bash
  $ which journalctl  # systemd 253 (253) from --version
  /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/journalctl
  $ sudo which journalctl  # systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.22) from --version
  /bin/journalctl
  ```
- There is no alias to `journalctl`

What is the logic behind this behavior?

How can I change that, so by default `journalctl` always use current system time zone?

Comment: Interesting...on my Ubuntu 22.04 system, this does not happen. Is there an alias for `journalctl` floating around? Can't imagine what would have changed from 20.04 to 22.04.

Comment: Does `systemctl status service_name` do the same thing?

Comment: @PabloA that’s an important piece of information no one could have guessed, would you mind adding it to your question? Does `/bin/journalctl` work properly?

Comment: @ajgringo619 I moved the info to the question.